# How to control PulseAudio volume using multimedia keys

Tags: pulseaudio, xfce, volume-control

I have installed pulse audio in xfce. Now I want to control volume using multimedia keys. I already tried xfce4-mixer and xfce4-volumed. But they change volume at hardware level using alsa driver. This makes a problem. when I mute audio, it mutes. But when I un-mute audio then it doesn't toggle. What should I do?

Comment: Using `pulseaudio-plugin`in the XFCE panel and configuring  it to use `pavucontrol`as audio mixer, the volume control keys work on the default output of pulseaudio, and the `mute`key works on all outputs.

Comment: Does running `amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle`  in Terminal mute and unmute it?

Answer (score 4):

In Keyboard > Application Shortcuts, you can set the following commands for your volume media keys.

Mute and unmute:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle
```

Volume down:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
```

Volume up:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
```

For the bottom two commands you can of course set it to the percentage you prefer.